# PC repeatedly turning OFF and ON due to CPU overheat

Tags: cpu

I'm using HP desktop for a few months, today I turned it ON, it normally booted up then after like 5 seconds it turned OFF, it automatically turned ON again and after a few seconds turned OFF, the process keeps repeating.

I removed all the additional devices and memory sticks, cleaned them, started connecting devices one by one, the same problem existed. Finally, I found some article which said the problem may be caused by heated-up CPU, I just unplugged the FAN which was mounted over the CPU, the Fan was physically not removed, I turned on my CPU and used my Air Blower as a Fan by blowing Air on the UNPLUGGED CPU Fan, which made the Fan run too Fast, the computer was running ALL OK and I noticed, it was much faster than the previous sessions. When I turn OFF the Air Blower, the computer turns OFF and the same problem exists.

So far, I've diagnosed the problem, but need help to make it FIX.

Answer (score 1):

It is common that the thermal transfer grease between the heat sink and the processor face will dry and become ineffective. You improved some of the heat transfer with your blower, but only temporarily.

Consider to carefully remove the heat sink and fan assembly from the processor, clean both mating surfaces (heat sink and processor top) and reapply a thin uniform layer of thermal transfer paste.

Use caution when separating the heat sink from the processor. The previously applied grease can cause the two to stick together. This would result in the heat sink pulling the processor from the socket. If you can release the socket prior to lifting the heat sink, you reduce the chance of damage.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal grease as noted above seems most likely. Make sure the Air Blower did not blow dust and dirt into the fan, clogging it as that could also cause overheat